# Сохранение в файл

Tags: delphi

есть такой оператор     Memo1.lines.savetofile...сохраняет строки с мемо в файл. Есть ли оператор, чтоб сохранять текст с Edit в файл без копирования в мемо?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А обычной записью в файл нельзя воспользоваться?

к примеру:

```
var f: TextFile;
    Text:string;

begin
  text := Edit1.Text;
  AssignFile(f, text);
  Rewrite(f);
  Closefile(f);
```

Comment: а как сохранить файл не в папке с проектом, а самому вblбрать место при сохранении?

Comment: AssignFile(f, 'С:\путь\к\моему\файлу');

Comment: использовать opendialog (нужно взять с вкладки dialogs)

    if not OpenDialog1.execute then exit;
    text := Edit1.Text;
    AssignFile(f, OpenDialog1.filename);
    Rewrite(f);
    writeln(f,edit1.text);
    Closefile(f);

Comment: кстати ваш код создает файл с именем с Edit1, а не то что надо=(

Answer (score 0):

Можно так:

---

```
begin
assignfile(output,' имя файла '); //связываем переменную output, которую обьявлять  не надо, с файлом//  
append(output); //открываем для записи файл//  
writeln(edit1.text);//выводим в файл текст//  
close(output);//закрываем файл//  
end;
```

---

Можно, но тогда перед запись надо будет осуществлять как:
    writeln(f,edit1.text); //а у меня короче

Comment: не работает ваш код почему-то

Comment: А что именно не работает?